# Sources For Comparing a House to a Sanctuary

Tags: beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle, home-house, allegory-mashal

Are there sources that compare or refer to a house as a משכן or מקדש (expressions for holy sanctuaries)?

---

Besides for "Beis Rav" in Megillah 29a which possibly means his Yeshiva.

Comment: I don't have a source at hand @mevaqesh but comparing one's home to the Holy Temple most certainly is in Jewish literature. I would start by searching Chabad website as this concept has a relationship to mysticism and Kabbalah. Interesting, a secular concept exists as well as in "a man's house is his castle."

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/860677/jewish/The-Temple-at-Home.htm   I'll try to get more sources @mevaqesh

Answer (score -2):

1. There's a Gemara on the last Daf of Chagiga ([27a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01139.html#HtmpReportNum0050_L2)):

> רבי יוחנן וריש לקיש דאמרי תרוייהו בזמן שבית המקדש קיים מזבח מכפר על אדם **עכשיו שלחנו של אדם מכפר עליו**

Both R' Yochanan and Reish Lakish say when the Temple  exists the [sacrifices brought on the] altar atone for a person, **nowadays a person's table atones for his sins.**

To which Rashi explains:

> **שולחנו מכפר עליו**. בהכנסת אורחין

This is a result of inviting [and feeding] guests.

2. There's a Gemara in Gitin ([17a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00933.html#HtmpReportNum0030_L2)):

> דריש ר''ע איש ואשה זכו שכינה ביניהן לא זכו אש אוכלתן

Rabbi Akiva taught that if a husband and wife are meritorious, then the Divine Presence rests between them. If they are not, then fire consumes them.

The essence of the  משכן or מקדש  was the presence of the Shechina.

Comment: There are many thing that bring shechina that arent compared to a mishkan; e.g. an individual who learns